# How to use kubernetes secrets in nodejs application?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, kubernetes

I have one **kubernetes cluster** on **gcp**, running my **express** and **node.js** application, operating **`CRUD`** operations with **`MongoDB`**.

I created one secret, containing `username` and `password`,
connecting with `mongoDB` specifiedcified secret as `environment` in my `kubernetes` **`yml`** file.
Now My question is "**How to access that username and password
in node js application for connecting mongoDB**".

I tried `process.env.SECRET_USERNAME` and  `process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD`
in `Node.JS` application, it is throwing **`undefined`**.

Any idea ll'be appreciated .

**Secret.yaml**

```
 apiVersion: v1

  data:

     password: pppppppppppp==

     username: uuuuuuuuuuuu==

kind: Secret

metadata:

 creationTimestamp: 2018-07-11T11:43:25Z

 name: test-mongodb-secret

 namespace: default

 resourceVersion: "00999"

 selfLink: /api-path-to/secrets/test-mongodb-secret

 uid: 0900909-9090saiaa00-9dasd0aisa-as0a0s-

 type: Opaque
```

**kubernetes.yaml**

```
 apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
 
kind: Deployment

metadata:

annotations:deployment.kubernetes.io/

revision: "4"

creationTimestamp: 2018-07-11T11:09:45Z

generation: 5

labels:
    name: test
 name: test
 namespace: default
 resourceVersion: "90909"
 selfLink: /api-path-to/default/deployments/test
 uid: htff50d-8gfhfa-11egfg-9gf1-42010gffgh0002a
spec:
  replicas: 1
   selector:
   matchLabels:
   name: test
 strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
     maxSurge: 1
     maxUnavailable: 1
    type: RollingUpdate
  template:
     metadata:
      creationTimestamp: null
  labels:
    name: test
  spec:
    containers:
  - env:
    - name: SECRET_USERNAME
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: username
          name: test-mongodb-secret
    - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
      valueFrom:
        secretKeyRef:
          key: password
          name: test-mongodb-secret
    image: gcr-image/env-test_node:latest
    imagePullPolicy: Always
    name: env-test-node
    resources: {}
    terminationMessagePath: /dev/termination-log
    terminationMessagePolicy: File
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  schedulerName: default-scheduler
  securityContext: {}
  terminationGracePeriodSeconds: 30
 
  status:
   availableReplicas: 1
   conditions:
  - lastTransitionTime: 2018-07-11T11:10:18Z
     lastUpdateTime: 2018-07-11T11:10:18Z
    message: Deployment has minimum availability.
     reason: MinimumReplicasAvailable
    status: "True"
     type: Available
     observedGeneration: 5
      readyReplicas: 1
      replicas: 1
      updatedReplicas: 1
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your`kubernetes.yaml` file specifies which environment variable to store your secret so it is accessible by apps in that namespace.

Using [kubectl secrets cli interface](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/secret/) you can upload your secret.

```
kubectl create secret generic -n node-app test-mongodb-secret --from-literal=username=a-username --from-literal=password=a-secret-password
```

(the namespace arg `-n node-app` is optional, else it will uplaod to the default namespace)

After running this command, you can check your kube dashboard to see that the secret has been save

Then from you node app, access the environment variable `process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD`

Perhaps in your case the secretes are created in the wrong namespace hence why `undefined` in yourapplication.

**EDIT 1**

Your indentation for `container.env` seems to be wrong

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: secret-env-pod
spec:
  containers:
  - name: mycontainer
    image: redis
    env:
      - name: SECRET_USERNAME
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: username
      - name: SECRET_PASSWORD
        valueFrom:
          secretKeyRef:
            name: mysecret
            key: password
  restartPolicy: Never
```

Comment: I created secrets and it has been saved in my gcp kubernetes dashboard . and i declared also in kubernetes.yaml file as env . 

when I am trying to access username through my code , it is throwing undefined . 

``` var myvalue=process.env.SECRET_USERNAME;
    console.log(myvalue);
 ```

Comment: I think i see the problem. Indent your env vars in the container block in your yaml file. see my edited answer

Comment: i fixed indent in yaml file , now it is giving me empty data for username and password. may you provide me any link if possible.

Comment: Thats a good sign i think, at least it is reading the `test-mongodb-secret` secret. Maybe the secret was uploaded wrongly as well.  Delete the secret and re add it using the cli command (just to test) I gave above. The relevant link is in my answer above

Comment: i deleted old one and re-added it , still it is empty. above link I have already read, unfortunately it does not have any single example for using secrets in any application(viz. node,java or elixir.).

Comment: still have issues ?

Comment: I resolved . Actually  I thought it should print in my nodeJS app. but it does not. since my username/password was showing empty then i understood it ll not print .I just put like this
 **var url="mongodb://process.env.SECRET_USERNAME:process.env.SECRET_PASSWORD@HOSTNAME/DBNAME" ** and it worked for me. Thanks Sir. I have understood fully how to use secrets in Node Js app for kubernetes. upvoted.